# Displaying a HTML select value in the same page

Tags: php, html

Basically I just want to have a value set by a dropdown box and then echo the value next to it, ideally without a submit button and in the same page.

```
<select name="price" action="post" id="mySelect">
<option value="100">Option 1</option>
<option value="120">Option 2</option>
<option value="115">Option 3</option>
<option value="135">Option 4</option>
<option value="80" >Option 5</option>
</select>

echo "£ $price"
```

I've been looking for a while for a way to do this, most solutions echo the value into the select. I'm sure there's a much better way to do this so any links would be appreciated!

Comment: you have to use javascript for that.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server to produce a html file. You need to use a clientside language to achieve this.

Comment: You can use Ajax for that.

Comment: @LozCheroneツ I meant in conjunction with... (JS) ;-) didn't have time to edit my comment.

Comment: Whilst you could use Ajax, there wouldn't be much point unless you wish to grab some information about the selection from a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use javascript for this without submitting.

```
<select name="price" action="post" id="mySelect" onChange="document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML = this.value;">
<option value="100">Option 1</option>
<option value="120">Option 2</option>
<option value="115">Option 3</option>
<option value="135">Option 4</option>
<option value="80" >Option 5</option>
</select>
<p>£ <span id="selectedValue"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function(){
    $('#DisplayValueSomewhereID').html($('#mySelect').val());
});
```

The somewhere on the page:

```
<div>&pound;<span id='DisplayValueSomewhereID'>0.00</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <select name="price" action="post" id="mySelect" onchange="return show_price(this.value);">
    <option value="100">Option 1</option>
    <option value="120">Option 2</option>
      <option value="115">Option 3</option>
    <option value="135">Option 4</option>
    <option value="80" >Option 5</option>
    </select>

    <div>&pound; <span id="price_sp"><span></div>
<script>
    function show_price(price)
    {
        document.getElementById('price_sp').innerHTML = price;
    }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Doesn't work](http://jsbin.com/wemaluqe/1/edit?html,output) (and the question says PHP, not JavaScript).

Comment: @Quentin He was not sure what to use he just want the form should not be submitted and he ask for a better way if possible

Answer (score -2):

1. Add a form
2. Add a submit button to the form (you have to have some way to tell the browser to send the form data to the server)
3. Read the value from `$_POST[]` (if it exists)
4. Protect yourself from XSS attacks

such:

```
<form method="post">
<select name="price" id="mySelect">
<option value="100">Option 1</option>
<option value="120">Option 2</option>
<option value="115">Option 3</option>
<option value="135">Option 4</option>
<option value="80" >Option 5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
        echo "$";
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['price']);
    }
```

Comment: It was clearly mentioned in the question that he do not want to submit the page then your answer is off topic

Comment: @Veerendra — No, the question say "**ideally** without a submit button". To achieve this with PHP (the only programming language tagged in the question), the form has to be submitted so the submit button is required.

Comment: @Quentin Surely its best to suggest the best language to use for the problem, rather than making the OP use the language he thinks he needs, but doesn't really.

Comment: @Jono20201 — Using a server side language for this is a sensible, reliable approach.

Comment: @Quentin Just to display the the price on the same page on change of a simple dropdown why need to connect to server when it can be done on client side and much more faster without server side

Comment: *"Using a server side language for this is a sensible, reliable approach."* - I agree. Plus, if user has JS disabled, then a JS solution would be useless. I always use server-side scripting, rarely will I use JS unless I have to.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using JavaScript to implement a progressively enhanced, more user-friendly approach once the fundamentals are done … but getting the fundamentals done first is still a good idea.